# re writing or formatting contents in .txt file to add numbering in front and semi colon at the end

Tags: php, file

I have a .txt file with content(see first image) I need the content in such a way that It should be numbered and  comma at the end of every line(see second image).

[image: First Image: original content in the file]

[image: Second Image: desired contents in the file]

1. I want to insert say: "1"=>" in front of the first line. The numbering will increase on the second line so having about 4747 lines the last number will be 4747.
2. then insert: ", at the end of every line.

I have some knowlege in PHP so if somebody has solution or idea that will be helpful. I have been formatting this manually and that is very time consuming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP's [file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), which will give you an array with one element for each line. After that it should be a simple matter of iterating over the array with `foreach` and concatenating the appropriate bits onto the string. Then use `fopen()` and `fwrite()` to write the edited lines to your output file.

Answer (score 2):

Using PHP:

1. open your original file (consider fopen() or file_get_contents)
2. Split into an array by newline (explode())
3. process array line by line (for or foreach)
4. prepend the current line number
5. append quote and comma
6. loop to next array member
7. When finished - save content to file (file_put_contents())

That should be enough for you to work it out for yourself!